# Run package specs in Atom Editor always causes error

Tags: macos, atom-editor

Atom Editor can be found here: https://atom.io/

Discourse thread about this issue here: http://discuss.atom.io/t/application-run-all-specs-fail-to-run/7541

I am running: MBP (OS X 10.9.2) with Atom 0.84.0 and Node 0.10.26.

When I do View > Developer > Run atom specs
- Nothing happens, no window opens, inspector doesn't open

When I do

```
apm develop vim-mode
cd ~/github/vim-mode
atom .
```

View > Developer > Run package specs
- Nothing happens, no window opens, inspector doesn't open

I then tried

```
~/github/vim-mode $ apm test
[764:0409/142738:INFO:renderer_main.cc(227)] Renderer process started
```

No window opened, however another Atom program launched with a menu containing "Atom > [Reload, Close, Toggle, Quit]"

[image: img]

After pressing Quit, the terminal said "Tests passed". None of the other buttons worked

[image: img]

```
~/github/vim-mode $ apm test
[645:0409/141838:INFO:renderer_main.cc(227)] Renderer process started
Tests passed
```

I don't think they actually passed, "Tests passed" only showed up after quitting the window

I then tried `atom -d`

[image: img]

And an identical program started with no window

I then tried running tests via another way

```
~/github/vim-mode $ atom -t
[833:0409/143232:INFO:renderer_main.cc(227)] Renderer process started
[831:0409/143236:INFO:CONSOLE(27)] "Error: Cannot find module '../lib/ui-watcher.coffee'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:279:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:363:17)
  at require (module.js:379:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/dev-live-reload/spec/ui-watcher-spec.js:8:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/dev-live-reload/spec/ui-watcher-spec.js:185:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:455:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:473:10)
  at Module.load (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:363:17)
  at require (module.js:379:17)
  at requireSpecs (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-suite.coffee:9:5)
  at runAllSpecs (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-suite.coffee:47:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-suite.coffee:58:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-suite.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:455:26)
  at Object.requireCoffeeScript [as .coffee] (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/coffee-cache.js:64:19)
  at Module.load (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:363:17)
  at require (module.js:379:17)
  at module.exports.runSpecSuite (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/jasmine-helper.coffee:30:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-bootstrap.coffee:24:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-bootstrap.coffee:2:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:455:26)
  at Object.requireCoffeeScript [as .coffee] (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/coffee-cache.js:64:19)
  at Module.load (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:363:17)
  at require (module.js:379:17)
  at window.onload (file:///Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/index.js:20:5)
", source: /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/spec/spec-bootstrap.coffee (27)
```

Comment: I submitted a bug report about this: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not relevant any longer, problem solved after reinstallation.